# Reference type fields are null in IParameterInspector .BeforeCall

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I implement IParameterInspector interface. When I call methods which have primitive type parameters Beforecall works fine! But something goes wrong when I pass a custom reference type object. When I pass reference type parameter all the fields of the object get default values.

```
object IParameterInspector.BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
{
        var argument = (MyCustomType)inputs[0];
        if (argument != null)
        {
            // All the fields are null, e.g.argument.ID is null
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, Solved!! `DataMember` attribute was missing on the fields :)